# Most widely used metric for determining ideal amount of parameters in a linear model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, applications, linear-regression, regression-analysis

We are at a point in my Applied Statistics class where we are allowed to use whatever metrics we want to support the creation of a linear model.  We have covered R-squared, Mallows Cp, AIC, and BIC, but I was wondering which one of these is either the simplest and/or most used in the real world, thanks!

Comment: "most used in the real world" inevitably goes to R-squared, and that's not a good thing. Incidentally, it's also probably the simplest. (And again, please don't use it for model selection.)

Comment: Of the last three on your list (which *are* intended for model selection), AIC is probably the most widely used. But selection via some kind of cross-validation is more common. (Also there's things like LASSO)